OR-Tools CP-SAT solver: How modeling Flow constraints
I try to modeling this constraint (flow conservation constraint): Xi = sumj(Zij) = sumj(Zji). So i tried the first part : Zji <= Xi , after that, i used AddImplication like model.AddImplication(Xi, Sumj(Zij)) but it not worked. It is possible to use model.Add(sumj(Zij) == Xi)  but it is time consuming to resolve.
Please, is their others possibility to modeling this constraint in sat-cp format from google or-tools. Thanks

Just use the sum formulation, and write linear equations for flow conservation.

Thanks, i try it and it consume time, and the gap after 20 min is 80%. CpSolverResponse summary:
status: FEASIBLE
objective: 705892
best_bound: 139016
integers: 1327
booleans: 72801
conflicts: 132
branches: 162463
propagations: 17599138
integer_propagations: 3608747
restarts: 97261
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 1200.85
usertime: 1200.85
deterministic_time: 1985.02
gap_integral: 26338
solution_fingerprint: 0x69d5619f962f5da1

you should use more that 1 worker. Can you send me the model ? model.export_to_file('slow_flow.pb.txt') in python

i try with 16 workers, the gap is hight: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sjjNpkKz2nc7MWEv9nuoNJQh0H7EMLJz/view?usp=drive_link

Your model has 1.2M Boolean variables, and 1.2M Linear equations. It is not surprising the gap is high.
